# Creating unique identifier column(1 or zero) Rank () SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, rank

I am trying to create a column in SQL SERVER that shows 1 OR 0(zero). I have a column of customer numbers that appear more than once. At the first hit on a unique non-repeated customer number it should show one and if it is repeated then 0(zero). How can I create this ?

```
CustNumber  Unique
25122134      1
25122134      0
25122134      0
25122136      1
25122136      0
```

the solutions I am considering and trying out now are Rank() and Rank_DENSE().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @test table
(
    CustNumber   int 
)

insert into @test values
(25122134),
(25122134),
(25122134),
(25122136),
(25122136)

select 
    * ,
    // each CustNumber in partition has the same rank, but different row_number
    case when (row_number() over (partition by CustNumber order by CustNumber)) = 1
         then 1 else 0 end as [Unique]        
         // the 1st is unique, the rest (2..n) are not
from @test    
order by CustNumber, [Unique] desc   
// unique in each group should be displayed first
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution  I did not know you could do this:case when (row_number() over (partition by CustNumber order by CustNumber)) = 1
I thought you had to do that at the end of the bracket by saying WHERE row=1. Thank you! Learnt something new:)

Answer (score 2):

You don't want [`RANK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) because that, by definition, produces the same output for identical inputs.

[`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and a simple [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression should do it:

```
;WITH Numbered as (
  SELECT CustNumber,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustNumber
                          ORDER BY CustNumber) as rn --Unusual - pick a real column if you have a preference
  FROM YourUnnamedTable
)
SELECT CustNumber,CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as [Unique]
FROM Numbered
```

Comment: Very interesting solution for me as a newbie. Is it possible to have it all in on single query?  Something like CASE WHEN Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer)=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0

Comment: It is a single query - a [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (`Numbered`, here) is just a way of separating out some of the logic so that I don't have to repeat things. Whilst [ASh's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30342185/15498) also doesn't (currently) repeat things, it would have to if you wanted to do more with the `ROW_NUMBER()` results.

Comment: Thank you. I learnt a lot from understanding your code. It widened my repertoire to solve more things in SQL SERVER instead of taking out the data and solving it in excel. Thank you!